# Tensorflow: Convolutions with different filter for each sample in the mini-batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mini-batch

I would like to have a 2d convolution with a filter which depends on the sample in the mini-batch in tensorflow. Any ideas how one could do that, especially if the number of sample per mini-batch is not known?

Concretely, I have input data `inp` of the form `MB x H x W x Channels`, and I have filters `F` of the form `MB x fh x fw x Channels x OutChannels`.

It is assumed that

`inp = tf.placeholder('float', [None, H, W, channels_img], name='img_input')`.

I would like to do `tf.nn.conv2d(inp, F, strides = [1,1,1,1])`, but this is not allowed because `F` cannot have a mini-batch dimension. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `tf.expand_dims` to add a 'fake minibatch dimension', then use `tf.nn.conv3d`, where the filter-depth matches the batch size. Not sure how well that would go with variable batch size.

Comment: @RobertLacok that sounds like a great idea. The only problem is that if I do that I don't know the size of the new spatial dimension (the mini-batch dimension). But I will try ... maybe it works anyway ...

Comment: I imagine that you need to know the upper bound on it and initialize the weights (filters) with that dimension. Then on runtime you could do something like `batch_size = tf.shape(input)[0]` to infer the dimension and use only a slice of the filter. Purely a suggestion though, I never tried anything like that so it might cause issues.

Comment: @RobertLacok, I think I was successful using `tf.nn.conv3d`. If you want to write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: The `batch_size = tf.shape(input)[0]` doesnt work though because the dimension is unknown, but it seems that it is not needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting back. Feel free to edit the answer if you found out more on the way.

Comment: For me using `tf.map_fn` worked best since it gets around both reshaping, which can mess things up, and using the batch size as a value which is often unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the proposed trick is actually not right. What happens with a `tf.conv3d()` layer is that the input gets convolved on depth (=actual batch) dimension AND then summed along resulting feature maps. With `padding='SAME'` the resulting number of outputs then happens to be the same as batch size so one gets fooled!

EDIT: I think a possible way to do a convolution with different filters for the different mini-batch elements involves 'hacking' a depthwise convolution. Assuming batch size `MB` is known:

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [MB, H, W, channels_img])

# F has shape (MB, fh, fw, channels, out_channels)
# REM: with the notation in the question, we need: channels_img==channels

F = tf.transpose(F, [1, 2, 0, 3, 4])
F = tf.reshape(F, [fh, fw, channels*MB, out_channels)

inp_r = tf.transpose(inp, [1, 2, 0, 3]) # shape (H, W, MB, channels_img)
inp_r = tf.reshape(inp, [1, H, W, MB*channels_img])

out = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(
          inp_r,
          filter=F,
          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
          padding='VALID') # here no requirement about padding being 'VALID', use whatever you want. 
# Now out shape is (1, H, W, MB*channels*out_channels)

out = tf.reshape(out, [H, W, MB, channels, out_channels) # careful about the order of depthwise conv out_channels!
out = tf.transpose(out, [2, 0, 1, 3, 4])
out = tf.reduce_sum(out, axis=3)

# out shape is now (MB, H, W, out_channels)
```

In case `MB` is unknown, it should be possible to determine it dynamically using `tf.shape()` (I think)

Comment: I edited the answer because I had mixed up some dimensions / transpose...

Comment: ... and a [gist](https://gist.github.com/drasros/cf2bea04d4e7c134a90e66156c626576) with the tests I did (using 1d convs, but this makes not difference)

Comment: Please note that this (otherwise great) answer is wrong in its current form. If the `padding = "VALID"`, than the `out = tf.reshape(out, [H, W, MB, channels, out_channels)` line should read `out = tf.reshape(out, [H-fh+1, W-fw+1, MB, channels, out_channels)` You form is correct, if you use `padding = "SAME"`. See my answer bellow for the correct for, treating both cases.

Comment: There is a small typo: there should be: `inp_r = tf.reshape(inp_r, [1, H, W, MB*channels_img])` instead of `inp_r = tf.reshape(inp, [1, H, W, MB*channels_img])`

Answer (score 5):

You could use `tf.map_fn` as follows:

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, h, w, c_in]) 
def single_conv(tupl):
    x, kernel = tupl
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, strides=(1, 1, 1, 1), padding='VALID')
# Assume kernels shape is [tf.shape(inp)[0], fh, fw, c_in, c_out]
batch_wise_conv = tf.squeeze(tf.map_fn(
    single_conv, (tf.expand_dims(inp, 1), kernels), dtype=tf.float32),
    axis=1
)
```

It is important to specify `dtype` for `map_fn`. Basically, this solution defines `batch_dim_size` 2D convolution operations.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is slightly wrong in how it treats the dimensions, as they are changed by padding = "VALID" (he treats them as if padding = "SAME"). Hence in the general case, the code will crash, due to this mismatch. I attach his corrected code, with both scenarios correctly treated.

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [MB, H, W, channels_img])

# F has shape (MB, fh, fw, channels, out_channels)
# REM: with the notation in the question, we need: channels_img==channels

F = tf.transpose(F, [1, 2, 0, 3, 4])
F = tf.reshape(F, [fh, fw, channels*MB, out_channels)

inp_r = tf.transpose(inp, [1, 2, 0, 3]) # shape (H, W, MB, channels_img)
inp_r = tf.reshape(inp_r, [1, H, W, MB*channels_img])

padding = "VALID" #or "SAME"
out = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(
          inp_r,
          filter=F,
          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
          padding=padding) # here no requirement about padding being 'VALID', use whatever you want. 
# Now out shape is (1, H-fh+1, W-fw+1, MB*channels*out_channels), because we used "VALID"

if padding == "SAME":
    out = tf.reshape(out, [H, W, MB, channels, out_channels)
if padding == "VALID":
    out = tf.reshape(out, [H-fh+1, W-fw+1, MB, channels, out_channels)
out = tf.transpose(out, [2, 0, 1, 3, 4])
out = tf.reduce_sum(out, axis=3)

# out shape is now (MB, H-fh+1, W-fw+1, out_channels)
```

Answer (score 3):

They way to go around it is adding an extra dimension using

```
tf.expand_dims(inp, 0)
```

to create a 'fake' batch size. Then use the

```
tf.nn.conv3d()
```

operation where the filter-depth matches the batch size. This will result in each filter convolving with only one sample in each batch.

Sadly, you will not solve the variable batch size problem this way, only the convolutions.