# Tensorflow: Convolve each image with a different kernel

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, how do I convolve each image in a minibatch with a different 2D kernel? Each minibatch of images has size `[10000, 32, 32]` and the corresponding filter has size `[10000, 2, 2]`---10000 kernels, each 2 pixels x 2 pixels. I'd like to get output with size `[10000, 31, 31]`. (I plan to set the stride lengths all to 1 and to use the "VALID" option to turn off padding, so the output images would have size 31x31 while the input images have size 32x32.)

In [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068999/tensorflow-convolutions-with-different-filter-for-each-sample-in-the-mini-batch), the solution was to add a "depth" dimension to the minibatch of images, and then to use conv3d rather than conv2d. But in that problem, the op seemed content to get just one image back as output, rather than one image as output for each sample in the minibatch.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` function does exactly what I wanted. I don't think there was any way to use `conv2d` or `conv3d` for the task.